# windows: unable to install kivy on virtual enviroment

Tags: windows, kivy, virtualenv, python-3.5

I have kivy installed on my system but I need an older version for my virtual env. 
I am getting the following error:

> command `cl.exe` failed: No such file or directory.

`cl.exe` is already been added to my system `PATH`. I have already installed Kivy on my PC without any errors and can use it normally.

My issue is in trying to install it in a virtual environment. I am trying to install using

```
python -m pip install kivy=="1.8.0"
pip install kivy=="1.8.0"
```

I can install Kivy 1.10 to the `venv` with no issues.

Comment: I have kivy installed on my system. my issue was trying to install another version of kivy to a venv.

Comment: Is `cl.exe` in PATH?

Comment: Yes. I was able to install kivy on my system, then I decided to create a venv so I could use an older version of kivy, that's when I first encountered this issue, so I added cl.exe to the PATH, this then gave me another error of io.h not recognized etc, etc.

Comment: Then you should [edit] you question and provide more info: what command(s) have you tried and what errors got. `'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory.` is certainly not enough. PS. I revoked my vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cl.exe is already been added to my system path

definitely nope otherwise you'd get a different error. Maybe you have a custom loader for Python (`.bat` file for example). You write you use `virtualenv`, therefore you need to add the **folder** where `cl.exe` resides to the `PATH` and **after** you activate the `virtualenv`. For example:

```
C:\> env_folder\Scripts\activate.bat
C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;"cl.exe folder"
C:\> cl.exe /?
```

Also note that this is a very unfortunate way for setting a path to `cl.exe`, because it's a compiler that supports **multiple** platforms. If you list the `bin` folder, you'll see multiple other folders named after archs the compiler supports in it and each of them has its own `cl.exe`.

You as a compiler user are supposed to launch it as it's said in the docs (or bear the consequences), therefore either choose one of the official launchers. If you use Visual C++ Build tools, the launchers are in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools
```

or `vcvarsall.bat` from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
```

Replace with your MSVC version of course.

That's being said, the support for MSVC (`cl.exe` compiler) **and** for Python 3.5+ was introduced in Kivy only recently with `1.10.0`, therefore even if you put that binary properly on your path (you have to run `vcvarsall.bat` in `virtualenv`) you'll most likely get a lot of errors and as it's not officially supported, you'll end up with the errors on your own.

What you can do is to use the compiler that was used for that particular version of Kivy and that is [MinGWPy](http://mingwpy.github.io/)([repo](https://anaconda.org/carlkl/mingwpy)) + [find the installation instructions](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commits/master/doc/sources/installation/installation-windows.rst) that were used for that version. If I remember correctly, `pygame` was still the main video provider back then (now it's `SDL2`).